# mistake in selectionSorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I start in the field and have a question regarding an array sorting.
I can not find the reason why the program did not have the array sorting 
thank you for your help .

the code

```
package sorting;

public class selectionSort
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        int []a={2,5,3,1,7,10,12};

        printArray(a);
        insertSort(a);
        printArray(a);
    }

    public static void insertSort(int[]array)
    {   
        for(int i=0;i<array.length-1;i++)
        {
            int smallestIndex=i;
            for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++)
            {
                if(array[smallestIndex]>array[j])
                {
                    smallestIndex=j ;
                }
                if(smallestIndex!= i)
                {
                    int temp=array[smallestIndex];
                    array[smallestIndex]=array[i];
                    array[i]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }//insertSORT


    public static void printArray(int[] array)
    {
        for(int i=0 ;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic of this type of sort should be:

- Find the smallest number in the array, and put it in the first place.
- Find the smallest number in the rest of the array, and put it in the second place.
- Find the smallest number in the rest of the array, and put it in the third place.

And so on.

The issue here is that you need to find which number is smallest in *all* of the rest of the array, and only after you finished scanning for the smallest, you should exchange that number with the *i*th element.

But your mistake is that you exchange the values while you are still scanning.

So, take the first round.

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬────┬────┐
│ 2 │ 5 │ 3 │ 1 │ 7 │ 10 │ 12 │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴────┴────┘
  0   1   2   3   4   5    6
```

Your *i*th element is 2. You scan through and you get j=3, the 1. You set `smallestIndex` to 3. And then you exchange them, and now you have

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬────┬────┐
│ 1 │ 5 │ 3 │ 2 │ 7 │ 10 │ 12 │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴────┴────┘
  0   1   2   3   4   5    6
```

This happens to be good - but you are still scanning. Your `j` now goes to 4, which is pointing to 7. The first `if` is not true. You don't change `smallestIndex`. However, its value is still `3` when you get to the second `if`. So you will now exchange again:

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬────┬────┐
│ 2 │ 5 │ 3 │ 1 │ 7 │ 10 │ 12 │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴────┴────┘
  0   1   2   3   4   5    6
```

And then again for j=5, and then back again when j=6. You end up with 2 back in the old place.

The solution is to move the exchange *outside* the `j` loop - after you have determined which index was the smallest index, only then you exchange them.

```
public static void insertSort(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        int smallestIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[smallestIndex] > array[j]) {
                smallestIndex = j;
            }
            // Not here!
        }
        // Do the swap outside the j loop.
        if (smallestIndex != i) {
            int temp = array[smallestIndex];
            array[smallestIndex] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The insertion sort algorithm goes in both ways, I mean you want your first for loop going from left to right, and the second going from right to left, starting from the position where your i has arrived.
You check the next number in the first for loop, if is smaller then the previous number you want to find the position where it belongs, and shift all other number to the right.

```
for(int i = 1; i < A.length; i++){
        if(A[i]<A[i-1]){
            for(int j = i; j > 0; j--){
                do{
                    int x = A[j-1];
                    A[j-1] = A[j];
                    A[j] = x;
                } while (A[j]<A[j-1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **SELECTION** sort and **INSERTION** sort are two different algorithms. Your method name is misleading.

There is information about their implementation here:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Selection_sort
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm_for_insertion_sort